# Tabbed android application basic structure

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm porting my app from iOS to Android and i want to give it the same tabbed layout as what happens with iOS tabbar.

I found out that currently the best way is an action bar with a fragment for each "tab". This is working, but i can't understand how to navigate inside every tab. For example: one tab fragment is a listfragment, when i tap on a list entry i want to push a new (fragment or activity?..suggestions) that displays details about that entry.

Inside the listfragment i'm using for the select event:

```
 getFragmentManager()
         .beginTransaction()
         .replace(what_goes_here?, detailsfrag)
         .commit();
```

anything i've tried just adds the detailsfrag above the listfragment.

Is this the correct layout? (3 tabs, one fragment each, and each one pushing fragments)
Bonus question: difference between fragment and fragmentactivity?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bonus question first: FragmentActivity is an subclass of Activity supposed to contain Fragments. It provides some common functionality e.g. a FragmentManager. You can use it, but don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an intent to launch a new FragmentActivity that however hides the actionmenu tabs. But this is the way it should be considering android best practices. As a matter of facts the fragment that i want to display should actually be an activity according to android's way of doing things.
Also twitter's app works this way so i think it's the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right course. The `.replace()` function takes to fragments - the one that should be replaced by the other. First one identified by its container id - e.g. `R.id.fragmentContainer`. Second one identified by an reference. Link [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.app.Fragment%29)

Comment: but i saw that the first argument is the container, not the fragment that is to be replaced...as a matter of facts i tried your suggestion using this.getid() but it doesn't work

Comment: You are right, I corrected my answer. Another hint: only dynamically added fragments can be replaced. Fragments defined in xml layout files can't be replaced.

Comment: Yeah they're dynamically added and that's why i can't understand which is the container for my listfragment..because if i use android.R.id.content it replaces everything (Also the other tabs). I used the default navigstion template provided by eclipse with tabs and pager navigation (FragmentPagerAdapter subclassing that returns the right fragment for the selected tab)

Comment: Ok. Getting closer. You need some kind of container. What about a ViewPager. It's often used in combination with ActionBar tabs and allows swiping.

Comment: it's there but if i use it in the replace call (R.id.pager), instead of loading the new fragment i get an empty page, and if i do a pair of swipes between tabs i get a Coreographer runtime exception